# Is the SELinux policy written into the kernel before or after PID1 executes?

Tags: selinux

I would like to know if the SELinux policy to configure the MAC of a system is put into the kernel before or after PID1 executes.

If it is loaded after PID1, does this mean that there is a window of time where PID1 can function unencumbered by SELinux policy?

If it is loaded before PID1, how is this accomplished?

Comment: U&L SE: [*How is SELinux loaded on boot?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472928/how-is-selinux-loaded-on-boot/472935)